# Java Encapsulation Constructor Method

Tags: java, constructor

Hi all I am working on a java code for student health. what I am trying do is

**A) Make a constructor method that initializes only the first 2 data fields
(name and date-of-birth). Also, increment the patient counter data field.**

**B) Secondly make a constructor method that initializes all the data fields. Also, increment the patient counter data field.**

If I recall correctly in order to make a constructor method that initializes the first two variables (in this case name and DOB) it goes something like this.

```
public emr (String name, Long dob){
```

However when I put that in my emr class my main method comes up with errors saying "constructor emr class cannot be applied to given types"

In my main Method I have

```
package studenthealthservices;

public class Studenthealthservices {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    emr p1 = new emr();

    p1.setName("Colin");

    emr p2 = new emr();
    p2.setName("Anquan");

    emr p3 = new emr();
    p3.setName("Buster");

    emr p4 = new emr();
    p4.setName("Hunter");

    emr p5 = new emr();
    p5.setName("Nori");

}

}
```

This is my emr class code

```
package studenthealthservices;

public class emr {

private String name;
private Long dob;
private String rfv;
private double bodyt;
private double hr;
private String diag;
private String pmeds;

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getDob() {
    return dob;
}

public void setDob(Long dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}

public String getRfv() {
    return rfv;
}

public void setRfv(String rfv) {
    this.rfv = rfv;
}

public double getBodyt() {
    return bodyt;
}

public void setBodyt(double bodyt) {
    this.bodyt = bodyt;
}

public double getHr() {
    return hr;
}

public void setHr(double hr) {
    this.hr = hr;
}

public String getDiag() {
    return diag;
}

public void setDiag(String diag) {
    this.diag = diag;
}

public String getPmeds() {
    return pmeds;
}

public void setPmeds(String pmeds) {
    this.pmeds = pmeds;
}

}
```

Comment: Well, you don't show that specific constructor, nor do I see where you try to use it. BTW, you should follow Java naming conventions when naming `YourClass`.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not write a constructor, a public constructor with no arguments is created by default.

This default constructor is the constructor you are using in `main` when you write `new emr()`.

However, when you write your own constructor, then the default constructor will not be created, so `main` will no longer compile. If you want `main` to continue to compile even after you have written the new constructor, you will have to also write a second constructor with no arguments.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time using a constructor so I am not sure what that means. I will end up using the constructor to display

Name, Date of birth, reason for visit.
vitals (body temperature, heart rate)
diagnosis.
prescribed medicine.